# How to perform upsert operation in PostgreSQL on Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, cloud, upsert, google-cloud-data-fusion

I want to do operation upsert before write on PostgreSQL on Cloud Data Fusion, I can easily write with the sink plugin but I can't find how can I do the update if the value already exist, thanks.

Comment: look at insert with on conflict clause

Comment: There is no specific plugin available for performing upsert operation in PostgreSQL in Data Fusion. There is an INSERT ON CONFLICT statement in PostgreSQL  which can be used for your requirement as mentioned in the above comment. You can check out this [link](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/) that shows the specific PostgreSQL upsert implementation which can be used in the PostgreSQL sink in the Data Fusion console.

Comment: @ShipraSarkar so Should I create another table where to save the data and then, after save the datas with postgresql sink plugin, add another plugin, postgresql executor and write the command "on conflit" to write in my table, Did I understand right?

Comment: Yes, @Robs, what you understood is right.You can save the data to a temporary table first with Postgres sink, and then run a query using Postgres executor to merge (i.e. upsert) it with the target table.

Comment: Hi @Robs, Is the issue resolved for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @ShipraSarkar that there is no option in the Postgres sink plugin for an upsert operation. Thus, INSERT ON CONFLICT statement in PostgreSQL can be used for the same. As you rightly pointed out, first one can put the data in a staging table using the sink plugin  and then run a query using Postgres executor to merge (i.e. upsert) it with the target table.